# Simple webservice in VS 2012, cannot access the webmethod

Tags: web-services

I was trying to follow this tutorial to implement a simple webservice:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jK-cWZQqeJw

I have add a web reference and enter the free webservice url:

http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx

In this tutorial I see something like:

```
wService.Weather myService = new wService.Weather();

string result = myService.GetCityWeatherByZip("61761");
```

But I don't have the class Weather in my webservice. The only difference I see, is that I am using vs 2012 and the tutorial was in vs 2005 or 2008. How can I access the webmethod "GetCityWeatherByZip" ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2012:

1. Right-click the project and select "Add Service Reference".
2. Click "Advanced...".
3. Click "Add Web Reference..."
4. In the URL field, enter in http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx and then press enter.
5. Change the web reference name to anything you would like, and then click "Add Reference".

Try the following:

```
var client = new wservice.Weather();
var result = client.GetCityForecastByZIP("90210");
var city = result.City;
```

Comment: -1: the name of the service does not determine the name on the client, unless you want it to.

Comment: John, I appreciate the comment, but I guess I am confused on how I am incorrect.  I realize when adding a webservice as a reference, it can be named to anything the developer chooses.  However, what's available within that service can be changed by the host at anytime.  In this case, it looks like they did change it from "Weather" to "WeatherSoapClient".  I get the feeling that you misunderstood my answer and are a bit too quick to downvote.

Comment: Sorry, but they did not change the name to `WeatherSoapClient`. Take a look at the WSDL.

Comment: so, how can I access the webmethod GetCityForecastByZIP ? This is not working: wservice.WeatherSoapClient client = new wservice.WeatherSoapClient();
            var result = client.GetCityForecastByZIP("90210");

Comment: I just added an update with a better direction on how to accomplish this.  Let me know if this doesn't work though!  Sorry about the misleading information previously... we're all learning here!

Comment: your last piece of code is working. I didnt do step 2, click on the button advanced. What is the differance between this procedure and the other when you enter the webservice url direct as a service reference?